# Dynamically added a field in different forms using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, dry

I'd like to have a field that doesn't show at first, but if the user decided to input to it, then it will appear in the form.

I can use Jquery and do something like

```
$('input[example]')
    .bind('click', function() {
        $('#clickfield')
            .append('<input id="new_field" name="MODEL[new_field]" size="30" type="text">');
```

However, I'd like to add this field in several different forms for different models.
Since the model name is in the field, how would I write the Jquery script to be modular so I can use the same script for all my forms?

Comment: didn't understand really. what is `example`, `clcikfield` !!! will u show us the desired output on `http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to make a function with the names you want as input parameters:

```
addInput(form, id, modelName) {
    $(form).append(
             '<input id="'+id+'" name="'+modelName+'['+id+']" size="30" type="text">'
            );
}
```

Where `form` would be the selector of the field (`'#clickfield'` in the example case), `id` would be the id of the new input field, and `modelName` would be the name of the model you mentioned.

Other solution, assuming `'input[example]'` selects some button or clickable area that triggers the event of showing the field; and `'#clickfield'` is some `div` or `span` or some area where you will show your field, is to load these hidden fields from the server, styled as `display:none`, with a mnemonic class, so you could do something like define a function:

```
showField(clickable, class) {
    $(clickable).click(
        function(){
            $(class).show();
        }
    );
}
```

and then:

```
$(document).ready(
    showField('input[example1]', '.class1');
    showField('input[example2]', '.class2');
    showField('input[example3]', '.class3');
    //              .
    //              .
    //              .
    // One line for every clickable area that triggers
    // the event of showing a field, and the class of the
    // field to show
);
```

this way you could add some user friendly features like fading the field in with the `fadeIn()` Jquery function (instead of `show()`), or any other animation on appearing.

Hope you could use it! good luck!